# How to remove a property on a JSON Object

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a `JSON` response and I need to remove a property including the value and add it to a new list parsed in a `JSON` object as a response.

The `JSON` response is:

```
 [
    {
        "bookmark": "bla",
        "entity_name": "aag",
        "id": 56
    },
    {
        "bookmark": "ag",
        "entity_name": "dsg",
        "id": 34
    },
    {
        "bookmark": "agds",
        "entity_name": "dsaga",
        "id": 12
    }
   ...
]
```

I want to ammend this but splicing some of its properties (e.g. 'bookmark') and send it back as a `JSON` object.

It goes like this.

```
[
    {
        "entity_name": "aag",
        "id": 56
    },
    {

        "entity_name": "dsg",
        "id": 34
    },
    {

        "entity_name": "dsaga",
        "id": 12
    }
    ...
]
```

I have tried many ways but can't seem to get my desired output as above.

if the new list is similar to above:

```
return jsonify(newList)
```

Any suggestions would be highly helpful.
Thank you

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: So basically you just need to take the `bookmark` key out?

Comment: @gmds -yes exactly that

Answer (score 4):

For `python`

You can use `del` operator

Using your example

```
_collections = [{
    'bookmark': 'bookmark',
    'entity_name': "aag",
    'id': 56
},
{
    'bookmark': 'bookmark',
    'entity_name': "aag",
    'id': 56
},
{
    'bookmark': 'bookmark',
    'entity_name': "aag",
    'id': 56
}
]

for item in _collections:
    del item["bookmark"]

print(_collections)
```

For `javascript`

You can use `delete` operator.

Using your example:

```
var _firstCollection =  [
    {
        "bookmark": "bla",
        "entity_name": "aag",
        "id": 56
    },
    {
        "bookmark": "ag",
        "entity_name": "dsg",
        "id": 34
    },
    {
        "bookmark": "agds",
        "entity_name": "dsaga",
        "id": 12
    }
];

_firstCollection.forEach(item => {
   delete item.bookmark; // removes bookmark property of every item
});
console.log(_firstCollection);
```

Comment: This is a Python question

Answer (score 3):

Use the `json` library:

```
data = ...  # put your JSON object here

result = json.dumps([{k: v for k, v in d.items() if k != 'bookmark'} 
                     for d in json.loads(data)])
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[
  {"entity_name": "aag", "id": 56}, 
  {"entity_name": "dsg", "id": 34}, 
  {"entity_name": "dsaga", "id": 12}
]
```

There are a few steps to this solution.

First, if your input is a JSON object, then it must be converted to the appropriate Python object (usually a nested `dict` or `list`). That is done with `json.loads` (I remember it as "JSON load string").

Next, we can use a simple *comprehension* to get the result we want, which is a `list` of the same size, just with the `'bookmark'` key from each `dict` in it removed. The comprehension used is equivalent to the following:

```
loaded = json.loads(data)

result = []

for d in result:
    new_d = {}
    for key, value in d.items():
        if key != 'bookmark':
            new_d[key] = value

    result.append(new_d)
```

Lastly, of course, we convert our result back into a JSON object with `json.dumps`.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot, could you kindly explain me what you did

Comment: @gmds used [https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions]list comprehensions here, iterating each of entity and filtering keys with the if condition

Comment: This is perfect for filtering out 'ResponseMetadata' from boto3 responses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pop while iterating over your data.

```
import json
entities = [
    {
        "bookmark": "bla",
        "entity_name": "aag",
        "id": 56
    },
    {
        "bookmark": "ag",
        "entity_name": "dsg",
        "id": 34
    },
    {
        "bookmark": "agds",
        "entity_name": "dsaga",
        "id": 12
    }
]

for entity in entities:
  entity.pop("bookmark")

print(json.dumps(entities))
```

N.B. If you want to filter out multiple keys then you can do:

```
for entity in entities:
    for key in ["bookmark", "foo", "bar"]:
        entity.pop(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#You can do this without using json library as well-

mySourceList=[{"bookmark": "bla","entity_name": "aag","id": 56},{"bookmark": "ag","entity_name": "dsg","id": 34},{"bookmark": "agds","entity_name": "dsaga","id": 12}]

myTargetList=[]

for dict in mySourceList:
    myTempList=[]
    myTempDict={}
    for key,value in dict.items():
        if(key in ["entity_name","id"]):
            myTempList.append((key,value))
    myTempDict.update(myTempList)
    myTargetList.append(myTempDict)

print(myTargetList)

#O/P- [{'entity_name': 'aag', 'id': 56}, {'entity_name': 'dsg', 'id': 34}, {'entity_name': 'dsaga', 'id': 12}]
```